# Does minor shape shift qualify for warshaper?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, prestige-class, shapeshifting, alternate-class-feature, changeling

Does minor change shape, as in the changeling ability or the [shaper psion ACF](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/psm/20070314a), qualify a character for the warshaper prestige class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Four of the five options for qualifying for warshaper’s Special requirement involve having some specific form of shapeshifting: change shape supernatural ability, *polymorph* as a spell-like ability, *polymorph* as a spell, or wild shape or similar class feature. Minor change shape is a supernatural ability, but it’s not the “change shape” supernatural ability as found on the aranea, hound archon, barghest, doppelganger, rakshasa, or slaad monsters indicated in *Complete Warrior*’s examples.

**However**, changelings (but not necessarily shaper psions) do meet the Special requirement. That’s because there is a fifth way to qualify:

> - Shapechanger subtype (lycanthropes, phasm).

Per *Eberron Campaign Setting* pg. 13,

> #### Changeling Racial Traits
>
> - Shapechanger Subtype: Changelings are humanoids with the shapechanger subtype.

Thus, a changeling qualifies for warshaper.

As for the shaper psion, I would argue that *metamorphosis* should qualify a shaper for warshaper just as well as *polymorph* (but this would be a houserule you would have to ask the DM for; I just can’t imagine a reasonable DM denying it). Warshaper arguably remains a poor class for them, however, as it does not progress manifesting ability, and seven levels of shaper to qualify for *metamorphosis* is a lot to ask for someone primarily interested in warshaper.

Comment: Thank you. I note as I continue researching that Hengeyokai also qualify.